# A riddle - is there a way to solve it non-numerically?

Tags: prime-numbers, puzzle

So the riddle is:

John has written down $k$ sequential odd numbers: $n_1, n_2, ..., n_{k-1}, n_{k}$ (where $n_{2} = n_{1} + 2$ and so on). We know that:

- The sum of the first four numbers is a fourth power of some prime number (so $n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} +  n_{4} = p_{1}^4$ where $p_{1}$ is a prime number.
- The sum of the last five numbers is a fourth power of some prime number (so $n_{k} + n_{k-1} + n_{k-2} +  n_{k-3} + n_{k-4}= p_{2}^4$ where $p_{2}$ is a prime number.

The question is - how many numbers have been written down ($k=?$).

I've tried to solve it numerically, but without success - is there a way to solve it analitically?

EDIT: Sorry it's not even, it is ODD!

Comment: As stated, the riddle has no answer. The sum of the last five numbers is equal to $5n_{k-2}$, which is divisible by both $5$ and $2$. Thus it could not be a prime power.

Comment: Are you sure you gave the correct description? 
$$n_1+n_2+n_3 + n_4 = n_1+n_1+2+n_1+4 + n_1+6 = 4 n_1 +12 = p^4.$$ This shows $p$ is even, ie $p=2, p^4=16$. But this gives $n_1=1$ which is not even!

Comment: Of course! $4n_1=4$ implies $n_1=1$ and you said $n_1$ is even.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Still I don't think sequentially even => even

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - it should be ODD instead of EVEN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the correct formulation of the problem is:

> $n_{1}$ is arbitrary, and then $n_{i+1} = n_{i} + 2$.

In this case, the solution, as indicated in the other answers, should be
$$
1,3,5,7,\dots,121,123,125,127,129.
$$

*Proof.*

The sum of four consecutive such numbers is $4$ times the average of the first and last one, so for the first question the average must be $4$ (so that you get the fourth power of $2$), and the four numbers are $1,3,5,7$.

The sum of five consecutive such numbers is $5$ times the average of the first and last one, so for the second question the average must be $125$ (so that you get the fourth power of $5$), and the five numbers are $121,123,125,127,129$.

Comment: Which is heavily different to _k sequential even numbers_!

Comment: @gammatester, my guess is that *sequential even* means *spaced by two*.

Comment: Would you care to share how you got $k$?

Comment: @miniBill, just done.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of the first four is the fourth power of some prime then (assuming the first number is $n$) we get:$$n+(n+2)+(n+4)+(n+6)=p^4$$$$4n+12=p^4$$$$4(n+3)=p^4$$This implies $p$ must be even - the only even prime is $2$. Hence:$$4(n+3)=2^4$$Which leads to $n=1$. However, I just noticed in your question that you said the numbers are all even - which means there is no solution.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I don't think sequantially even => even

Answer (score 0):

Well, let $s = n\{1\}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^4 n\{i\}=p^4$ for some $p$, but the lhs is equal to $(s + s+2 + s+4 + s+6) = 8s + 12 = 4(s+3)$, so $4$ divides $p^4$, but $p$ is prime, therefore $p$ must be $2$ and $s + 3$ must be $4$, so $s = 1$.

Now the other piece.

$n\{k\} = 1 + 2k-2$, so $(1+2k-2+1+2k-4+1+2k-6+1+2k-8+1+2k-10) = 10k-25 = 5(2k-5)$ so the other prime is 5, and $2k-5=5^3=125$ so $2k=130$ and $k=65$